# Dart Difference in class method declaration

Tags: flutter, dart

What's the difference in declaring a method of a class this way:

```dart
Class Doc {
    Doc.fromObject(dynamic o) {
       // content
    }
}
```

and this way:

```dart
Class Doc {
    void fromObject(dynamic o) {
       // content
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one, creates a [named constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors). It return a new instance of Doc object.

```
class Doc {
    Doc.fromObject(dynamic o) {
       // content
    }
}
```

This one, it is just a class Doc with a method called fromObject (doesn't return anything)

```
class Doc {
    void fromObject(dynamic o) {
       // content
    }
}
```